# How can i set "Powered by Google" caption in AutoCompleteTextView in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
            I want to put "Powered by google" text at the end of my AutoCompleteTextView component in android.

Here is the image, to identify what i want?

[image]

I want exactly like above image. Please, help me to solve out this.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom layout for your text view

```
// inflate text view
    TextView textView =  (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtextview, null);


// this is a custom layout that you to add at the text view and it should include text and image view as your requirement  
  LinearLayout layoutForText = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_for_text);
layoutForText.addView(main);
```